# i want to use both query in the following code when is used orWhereNull i am getiing error how i can make my code to run

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to get the null expiry date result. My `whereRaw` is working fine but when I used `orWhereNull`, I get an error. Here is my code:

```
$offer_details = @\App\Offer::where('store_id',$store_id)->whereRaw('expiry_date > now()')->orWhereNull('expiry_date ')->get();
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting, please add that as well. ?

Answer (score 0):

Following query should work for you as, I don't thing 'orWhereNull()' available in laravel :

```
 $offer_details = @\App\Offer::where('store_id',$store_id)->
     ->whereNull('expiry_date')
     ->orWhereRaw('expiry_date > now()')  
     ->get();
```

Unlike that the "or" variant of 'whereRaw()' is availble as 'orWhereRaw()'.

More details of : **whereRaw / orWhereRaw**

The whereRaw and orWhereRaw methods can be used to inject a raw where clause into your query. WhereRaw() is a function of Laravel query builder which puts your input as it is in the SQL query's where clause.

Comment: problem remains same